# seleccionar de 2 combobox y mostrar datos en textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación y quede trabado en algo que no se como hacerlo.
Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente pero con `Entity Framework` sin usar `Ado`.

```
public void seleccionar_med()
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data 
    Source=NBX\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=clinica;Integrated 
    Security=True");
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from medicamento where 
    id_medicamento = '" + cbmedicamento.SelectedValue + "' ", con1);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        label9.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["stock"]);
        tbvencimiento.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["vencimiento"]);
        tbremito.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["remito"]);
        tblote.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["lote"]);
        label11.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["nombre"]);
        label9.Visible = true;

    }
    dr.Close();
    con1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, parece muy amplia tu pregunta. Tienes ya definidas tus entidades? En ese caso, debes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir todo el código relevante.

Comment: Has intentado algo con Entity Framework?

Comment: @Einer, esa es precisamente la pregunta, cómo hacerlo con EF.

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar tu entity framework:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lC-NfgP-0qo)

Una vez que tienes tu Entity Model, y usando *linq*:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    var datos = select m from context.Medicamento
        where m.id_medicamento = cbmedicamento.SelectedValue
        select new {
              stock = m.stock,
              ..
        }
}
```

Comment: si la aplicacion esta en 3 capas: Datos, lógica y presentación , como seria??

Comment: Ese es todo un tema... Si tienes alguna pregunta especifica, con gusto la tratamos de resolver.